# Azure Kubernetes - JMeter No X11 DISPLAY variable was set

Tags: azure, kubernetes, jmeter, kubernetes-helm

I am developing a **JMeter Dynamic Master-Slave Perf Environment** on top of **Azure Kubernetes** Service. In my JMeter Slave Deployment, the pod is getting into the `CrashLoopBackOff` state and creating another Pod again and this continues as a loop. While looking at the JMeter Slave logs, I have found out this error ​
`An error occurred: No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.`

Currently, I am using **Helm** to deploy the pods and below are my `jmeter-slave-deployment.yaml` and `values.yaml` files.

**`jmeter-slave-deployment.yaml` file**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}
  namespace: perf-platform
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.slave.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

    spec:
      
      containers:
     
      - name: distributed-jmeter-slave
        image: "{{ .Values.slave.image }}:{{ .Values.slave.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.slave.pullPolicy }}

        env:
        - name: HEAP
          value: "-Xms{{ .Values.slave.heap.xms1.memory }} -Xmx{{ .Values.slave.heap.xms2.memory }}"
        
        ports:
          - containerPort: 50000
          - containerPort: 1099
        
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.cpu }}"
          limits:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.cpu }}"
```

**`values.yaml` file**

```
#JMeter Slave Configuration
dep:
  name: distributed-jmeter
slave:
  replicaCount: 1
  image: gsengun/jmeter
  tag: 5.4.1
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  res:
    req:
      mem: "1024Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
    lim:
      mem: "1024Mi"
      cpu: "100m"
  heap:
    xms1:
      memory: "512m"
    xms2:
      memory: "512m"
```

Answer (score 0):

`No X11 DISPLAY variable was set` error means that you're trying to run JMeter in GUI mode and your (or whatever) image you're using doesn't have [X server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) installed/running

I fail to see the appropriate command to run JMeter Slave process so my expectation is that you need to amend your `jmeter-slave-deployment.yaml`  to have `command` directive specified like:

```
command: ["jmeter-server"]
```

if you like to copy and paste:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}
  namespace: perf-platform
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.slave.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ .Values.dep.name }}

    spec:
      
      containers:
    
      - name: distributed-jmeter-slave
        image: "{{ .Values.slave.image }}:{{ .Values.slave.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.slave.pullPolicy }}
        command: ["jmeter-server"]

        env:
        - name: HEAP
          value: "-Xms{{ .Values.slave.heap.xms1.memory }} -Xmx{{ .Values.slave.heap.xms2.memory }}"
        
        ports:
          - containerPort: 50000
          - containerPort: 1099
        
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.req.cpu }}"
          limits:
            memory: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.mem }}"
            cpu: "{{ .Values.slave.res.lim.cpu }}"
```

More information:

- [Define a Command and Arguments for a Container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker)